# how to get selected items for listfiled checkbox in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

i want to get the selected item values from listfield checkbox when clicking on some button .iam getting the selected index by using `int index1 = listField.getSelectedIndex();` but i want that selected item values i mean that string.how to get that please give your suggestions.i tried my code by refering this link [link is:](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_a_ListField_with_check_boxes.html?nodeid=1165752&vernum=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create following `MenuItem` and add that as you added the `_toggleItem`

```java
final MenuItem _getDataMenu =new MenuItem("Get Data", 200, 10) {
    public void run(){
        int index = _checkList.getSelectedIndex();
        ChecklistData data = (ChecklistData)_listData.elementAt(index);
        String message = "Selected data: " + data.getStringVal() + ", and status: " + data.isChecked();
        Dialog.alert(message);

        // get all the checked data indices
        IntVector selectedIndex = new IntVector(0, 1);
        CheckListData data;
        for (int i=0;i<_listData.size();i++) {
            data = (CheckListData)_listData.elementAt(i);
            if(data.isChecked()) {
                selectedIndex.addElement(i);
            }
        }
        data = null;
        // now selectedIndex will contain all the checked data indices.
    }
};
```

Comment: but iam getting only the lastly selected item.i want suppose i checked two items and then clicked on getdata means i need to display those both elements

Comment: just go through all the elements of _listData, check their status, and store them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

i think this code will give you the selected data

```
ChecklistData data = (ChecklistData)_listData.elementAt(index);
```

Comment: but iam getting only the lastly selected item.i want suppose i checked two items and then clicked on getdata means i need to display those both elements

Comment: use a for loop to find the selected datas